# Sibling component does not update on change

Tags: angular

I have two angular components which are not related. I am trying to pass data using a service. For some reason the component does not update.

Component 1:

```
...
constructor(private tableService: TableService) {}

addColumn(name: string): void {
    this.tableService.addColumn(name)
}
...
```

Component 2:

```
columns = []

constructor(private tableService: TableService) {}

ngDoCheck(){
    this.tableService.getColumns().subscribe(data => {
         this.columns = data
     })
}
```

Service:

```
...
currentColumns = new BehaviorSubject([
    'status',
    'picture'
])

getColumns(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.currentColumns.asObservable()
}


addColumn(name: string): void {
    const currentColumns = this.currentColumns.getValue()
    currentColumns.push(name)
    this.currentColumns.next(currentColumns)
}
```

Comment: ngDoCheck is wrong, this will add many subscriptions over time. Use ngOnInit and unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with subscribing your method in `ngOnInit` method instead of `ngDoCheck`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing as ngDoCheck, you need to use ngOnInit or ngOnChanges.
Created a sample for your reference
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ah4nhs